# How do I emulate the vmx feature with QEMU?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, hypervisor

I read from [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/nested-vmx.txt) that vmx capability support on QEMU must be explicitly enabled by providing the +vmx option to the command but the problem is that it does not seem to work. In my system, the VMX feature is still undetected.

Command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -no-kvm -cpu qemu64,+vmx,-svm  ...
```

In my guest OS, when I execute cpuid 1 I get ECX = 0x80802001; bit 5 = 0 meaning that my virtual CPU does not have VMX.

Is this a bug?

Or is there another way to enable the vmx feature in QEMU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command works for me:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -kernel kernel/kernel -serial stdio -enable-kvm
```

`-cpu host` makes QEMU report host CPU features inside the VM (so your CPU must support vmx)

`-enable-kvm` is required by `-cpu host`

Even though according to [this](http://website-humblec.rhcloud.com/nested-kvmvmx-or-guest-inside-guest/) `-cpu qemu64,+vmx` should work, it doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 4):

No, the `vmx` flag is not supported in the processor emulation mode of QEMU. In order to use `vmx` in QEMU, you must use KVM with QEMU (replacing `-no-kvm` with `-enable-kvm`); and your host processor must support `vmx`.

In [this document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/nested-vmx.txt) it shows the nested vmx instructions support in the Linux KVM; meaning this feature must be used with `-enable-kvm`.

In my test the options `-enable-kvm -cpu kvm64,+vmx` work, as the `vmx` feature is detected in the guest OS.