# QEMU debugging:: Warning:TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, qemu

I want to use `QEMU` to debug my compiled kernel `linux-4.13.4` on `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`

I follow the following steps:

#### 1 install qemu

```
sudo apt-get install qemu
```

#### 2 run qemu

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S -kernel /home/wxf/kernelSources/linux-4.13.4/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.13.4
```

Note:

> -s shorthand for -gdb tcp::1234
>
> -S freeze CPU at startup (use 'c' to start execution)

But I get the following warning:

```
warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
```

[image]

The terminal stops there and I cannot input other commands.

The QEMU window pops up when I run it but it is stopped.

[image]

## So, my question is

How to eliminate the warning and is it normal(since it is not an error information)?

Comment: vmx is for nested kvm. no need to bother with this warning unless you need it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154850/how-to-emulate-vmx-feature-with-qemu

Comment: my Qemu was killed by OOM kliler. -m 2G instead of -m 3G fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Frankly speaking, I don't know how to handle that warning, can it be ignored or have you to do something with it. But I suppose the main problem is that you cannot run the VM. If so, you need to properly determine where to enter that `c` to start the VM. :)

QEMU has several graphical interfaces (and AFAIK can even be run in plain console). Suppose we have identical defaults for which UI to use (probably, the GTK one). When I run similar command (`qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S -kernel ...`), I can switch to the monitor console of QEMU by pressing Ctrl+Alt+2 (just 2, not F2). There I press `c` (and Enter, it seems to behave like regular terminal) and then switch to the VM display by Ctrl+Alt+1.

[image: QEMU monitor console]

Answer (score 4):

You missed out giving the RAM size to be used by the VM. The default RAM allocated by qemu is 128M, which in your case was not sufficient, I guess. Try passing

> -m 512

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844496/qemu-system-x86-64-boot-failed)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, or something very similar. It gave the same warning and, while it would then boot, it was unusably slow.

I fixed it it by adding `-machine ubuntu,accel=kvm` to the `qemu-system-x86_64` command line.