# How to use QEMU to emulate X86 VMX without using KVM in Linux?

Tags: x86, virtualization, qemu

I am trying to use *pure* qemu emulator to emulate a X86 CPU to test VMX features.
I mean, I would boot a Linux on a VMX CPU which is emulated by qemu emulator, then in Linux, I will test VMX features.

I would like to know the parameters to start qemu (with VMX emulation enabled), and how to boot Linux in this emulated system, and where to check the log for qemu emulation.

Comment: [How to emulate vmx feature with qemu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39154850) indicates that `-cpu qemu64,+vmx` is supposed to work, but didn't.  Did you try that?  Also,  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#Running_virtualized_system has some basic intro stuff.  It has a section about enabling KVM, so read that and *disable* it.  (or probably `-disable-kvm`)

Comment: I checked the SO question, it said -cpu qemu64,+vmx did NOT work, so I did not try it. I would like to get the a real workable command line to start QEMU for the VMX emulation. I will google it more.

Comment: That was 2 years ago, and maybe that person was doing something else wrong.  I think it's worth trying if the docs still say it should work.

Comment: @wangt13 +vmx flag at cpu specification at command line only sets VMX support flag for CPUID instruction, to allow nested virtualization with kvm. When you disable kvm, then  qemu use TCG as engine. For TCG, each feature of guest ISA are handwritten in terms of TCG IR, here is [x86_64](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/target/i386/translate.c) rules ( try grep for intstr. names). So some (many) features are implemented in quite "workable" profile, or not implemented at all.  So, as current state of mainline qemu trunk, there are no VMX implemeted for x86 TCG.  Same as AVX2, FMA ...

Comment: That is really helpful. So now, it seems that I have to turn to BOCHS emulator for VMX emulation.

Comment: @wangt13 can you please tell if you succeeded in getting VMX emulation with BOCHS

Comment: Sorry for late response of 'No'. I have NOT touched this project for years, what BOCHS helped me is it listed the error codes for vmlaunch/vmresume, I can follow the BOCHS code to know what is wrong in my VMX operation.